# How to locate and click the textarea element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium with python and have been trying to click a text box, and input a message.
The text box's HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="tw-block tw-border-radius-large tw-pd-0">
    <div class="tw-relative">
        <div class="chat-input__textarea">
            <textarea data-a-target="chat-input" data-test-selector="chat-input" class="tw-block tw- 
            border-radius-medium tw-font-size-6 tw-full-width tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize" 
            autocomplete="Messenger-chat" maxlength="500" placeholder="Send a message" rows="1" 
            style="padding-right: 3.5rem;"></textarea>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I have been trying to select it by css selector with this code:

```
time.sleep(3)
input_box = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".textarea")
input_box.click()
for ch in message:
    input_box.send_keys(ch)
input_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

It keeps giving me a NoSuchElement. As you can see I don't really know what I am really doing- please help thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

`.texarea` is not going to find any element:

`.` indicates that the selector should look for the proceeding value in the `className` of an element.

So, you are telling the selector to look for an element with `className` textarea.

You are confusing `className` selector with a `tagname` selector. If you want to get it by tagname, you just use the tagname without any dot(.), so:

```
find_element_by_css_selector("textarea")
```

This would return the first textarea element it finds, which may or may not be what you want. To make it more precise you can do:

```
find_element_by_css_selector("textarea.tw-block.tw- 
        border-radius-medium.tw-font-size-6.tw-full-width.tw-textarea.tw-textarea--no-resize")
```

Notice how in the second version there are multiple dots(.) in the selector, telling the engine to search for an element of `tagname` textarea with `classNames`: `tw-block tw- 
            border-radius-medium tw-font-size-6 tw-full-width tw-textarea tw-textarea--no-resize`. Each individual className is seperated by a space in the `Html` markup, so you use a dot(.) to tell the selector to chain those classNames together.

If by chance you have multiple textarea's with all the same `classNames` as above, you'd need to find some kind of unique identifier for the textarea you want. So the selector provided by `KunduK` is a good example of that.

Perhaps this link will help you to learn more about css selectors: (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors)

Answer (score 2):

As per the HTML the element is a `<textarea>` element. So to identify the element the relevant code would have been either of the following:

- `browser.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea")`
- `browser.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea[attribute_name='attribute_value']")`

### Solution

Ideally, to identify and click within the desired element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  input_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea[data-a-target='chat-input'][data-test-selector='chat-input'][placeholder='Send a message']")))
  input_box.click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  input_box = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@data-a-target='chat-input' and @data-test-selector='chat-input'][@placeholder='Send a message']")))
  input_box.click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Your css selector is wrong `.textarea` in css selector identify the `class name`.

Try below **css** selector.

```
input_box = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea[data-a-target='chat-input']")
```